# How to disable cellular on Android Studio emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, cellular-network

Android Studio simulates a SIM card with T-Mobile by default. I would like an emulator with no SIM card installed (instead of simply disabling it with the likes of airplane mode). Is this possible to do in Android Studio, or is there any other emulator with this feature?